# How do you run a .cshtml on DotNetNuke

Tags: iis, razor, dotnetnuke

I am trying to add a webpage to a website that has already been put on IIS 7.5. I have scoured the internet in search of a solution trying to change the .config file, adding the dll files. The webpage runs fine when I run it as its own website but will produce errors when I setup its' own url off the already established website.

Here is the error:

```
"The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' 
or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To 
compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, 
remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the <compilation> element of the 
Web.config file. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution 
of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The value for 
the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if 
you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this 
Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 
'targetFramework' attribute from the <compilation> element of the Web.config file."
```

Comment: `.cshtml` is not a "webpage", per se.  It is an MVC view.  It will not resolve as a URL.

Answer (score 0):

CSHTML Files can be used in the Razor Host module in DNN. You'll need to add that CSHTML file into the module to display that within DNN.

That being said, are you sure that is what you really want to do?